# There is no Magento Connect in System

Tags: magento2, magento-connect, magento-connect-manager

I installed Magento 2 with sample data and NO extensions so far. Now I wanted to install a bought extension and in the installation-guide is a pointer to System -> Magento Connect -> Magento Connect Manager. But under System there is no Magento Connect. 

So I searched a little bit by myself and found a hint under http://192.168.xxx.xxx/Magento/downloader should be the side I am searching, but there is only a "404 Not Found"-Site. 
 Under System -> Integrations I found a point where you can activate some things. So I tried and activated the point "Available APIs" ->

```
System
    Magento Connect
       Connect Manager
       Package Extensions
```

But even after a relog as Admin, there is still no Magento Connect to see under System. Where could it be?

Comment: Magento 2 does not have Magento Connect  feature.I think it will be released once the new market place is live.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the extension you purchased is actually for Magento 2? Extensions from Magento 1 are not compatible.

If it is, the directions are wrong and you should ask them to fix it.

The Magento Connect Manager and downloader no longer exists as it did in Magento 1. There is a component manager for upcoming changes to Magento Connect (Marketplace), at `System > Tools > Web Setup Wizard`, but you can't upload an extension through it.

Comment: ok, found it, thanks... hm... i should call them and ask how they think i can install it.